# Elasticsearch segments builds up, heap increase until crash

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, heap-memory, segment, elasticsearch-2.0

I need some ElasticSearch help with an issue that's haunting me for a few months, without any real improvement no matter what I do.

I run a 6 nodes cluster, composed of 6 data nodes r4.xlarge (30.5GB), 3 of them are also eligible masters. Each node has 14GB of assigned HEAP memory.

The problem is as follows:
Heap saw teeth pattern is visible, but with time it gets smaller and smaller up to a point where a node will crash.
See example:
[image: ES Heap]

The heap is building up together with segments, you can see the spike in segments counts happens every night when a new daily index is created.

Our setup is composed of 2 main indices and 2 small indices, all mapped.
The 2 main indices have 4 shards with 1 replica, the small ones have 1 shard and 1 replica.

Daily index size of the main indices varies:

- impressions index - ~70-100GB daily, ~15m documents
- bids index - 25-40GB daily, ~13m documents
  On both, refresh_interval is set to 5s.

Indexing rate is not very high:
[image: indexing rate]
I'd even say its pretty low for such strong cluster.

Clearly there is some configuration issue causing segments to build up endlessly and create pressure on heap memory usage.

I've tried playing with the `shards count`, `number of replicas`, `refresh_interval` and more.. no good.
This setup of the cluster was even upgraded from m4.xlarge machines to the new r4.xlarge machines - this also had almost no effect at all!!

It's important to mention that we run real heavy queries with multiple aggregation levels on hourly basis, on up to 7 days of data (7 indices), but with such amount of RAM and correct indexing this shouldn't be a problem.

ElasticSearch version is 2.4.1, each r4.xlarge node consists of 30.5GB RAM & 1200GB SSD. All hosted on AWS of course.

Comment: do you see any "now throttling indexing" messages in your logs during the spike in segment count?

Comment: take a look at this if you haven't already: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html#segments-and-merging

Comment: @ArchitSaxena I have tried the following on each of the nodes: `grep -E 'throttle|throttling|indexing' /var/log/elasticsearch/*.log` - no results on any of them.

Comment: I have increased `indices.store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec` to 150mb. doesn't seem to make any difference looking at the last hour..

Comment: So, it doesn't seem to be linked to heavy indexing (which you had already reported lol). But you must have a lot of indices since you are creating new ones every day. What do you do about the old ones? Maybe try running an explicit `optimize` on them and see how it affects the segment count?

Comment: I said "Indexing rate is not very high" :)
Running optimize on old indices will probably work (its deprecated so I assume you mean force merge?), but it feels like its just hiding the problem rather than fixing handling the cause..
dont you think?

Comment: Yes, i meant force merge, apologies. I am still using elasticsearch 2.3 :D
I get your point. But, check this:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/cb67ce283e5bd22b0584f8498f966df62444dfd1/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/MergePolicyConfig.java#L109
line 109-114
Let's check the Index segments API?

Comment: side note: check the third video about tieredMerge: 
http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/02/visualizing-lucenes-segment-merges.html

Comment: @ArchitSaxena I already use force merging every few days to control the level of segments, otherwise my heap increases to a point it causes the node to fail..

Answer (score 0):

Did you set this on your nodes?

`indices.fielddata.cache.size: 20%`

By design, field data are loaded in memory when needed and never evicted. They will fill the heap until OutOfMemory exception. It’s not a bug, it’s a feature.

It’s critical to configure a cache limit to stop that “feature“.

I had clusters on ElasticSearch 2.x and they all run into that problem. I'm not sure whether it was adjusted in later versions to not systematically exhaust memory by default.

Use the stats API to see resources usage: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/cluster-nodes-stats.html